# How to change Image of RibbonFramework when change of Image ActionManager

Tags: delphi, ribbon

I use delphi 10.3.3 and [RibbonFramework](https://github.com/JAM-Software/RibbonFramework). I need change Image of RibbonFramework when change of Image ActionManager. I made interface in RibbonFramework and integrated with Delphi. In delphi I use ActionManager and ImageList. Imagelist connected with ActionManager. ActionManager connected with UIRibbon, roAssignImagesFromActionManager selected true. When I change ImageIndex of ActionManager then Image of RibbonFramework do not change.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TAComp.ImageIndex:=1;
end;

procedure TForm1.CommandCreated(const Sender: TUIRibbon;  const Command: TUICommand);
    begin
    case Command.CommandId of
         //ID команды Paste
         CmdComp:
         begin
         FCmdComp:=Command as TUICommandAction;
         FCmdComp.UseImageFromAction:=True;
         FCmdComp.ActionLink.Action:=TAComp;
         end;
       end;
    end;
```

How to change Image of RibbonFramework when change of Image ActionManager?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is set up correctly, the image should update automatically.
Does your Action "TAComp" belong to ActionManager? That would be important if you want the ribbon to update its commands' icons automatically.

Also: You don't really need to assign the action and the property "UseImageFromAction" manually here, you should use set "roAssignImagesFromActionManager" on the ribbon and let the markup file handle the connection between commands and actions. Just make sure to use the same name for your action as you did for your command in the ribbon designer. The ribbon will assign the action to the command automatically if the name matches.

Comment: I found mistake. I used guide, where author changed class Form from TForm to TUIRibbonform. It was mistake.